# In SwiftUI, what's the different ForEach without Identifier and with Identifier?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI, in the ViewBuilder, we have to use `ForEach` instead of `for`.

However, there are two ways of doing i.e.

```
ForEach(1...count, id:\.self)
```

and

```
ForEach(1..<(count+1))
```

Other than the syntax being different, is there any different use case for them?

Comment: If the type conform to Identifiable you don’t need to use `id:`.

Comment: You should use either in SwiftUI https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10022 right around minute 33

Comment: Performance. Javier in his [article](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-id/) provides insightful overview.

Answer (score 0):

Joakim has answered your question in the comments.

The second listed alternative can be used as long as the datatype being referenced is `Identifiable`. That means it is a class or has been declared as conforming to the Identifiable protocol. You can get `Identifiable` almost for free on your own objects by declaring conformance. The compiler will help you if you say you conform but don't, so that's a good place to start.

From Apple's Online Documentation:

> `Identifiable` provides a default implementation for class types (using ObjectIdentifier), which is only guaranteed to remain unique for the lifetime of an object. If an object has a stronger notion of identity, it may be appropriate to provide a custom implementation.

The first alternative exists for cases when it doesn't conform to `Identifiable`.